# C++ Segmentation fault in game

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am making a game in c++ using SDL. I have the main function witch just calls for the run game function. The run game function runs the game and should return 0 when exiting. I have tried to print things before and after every call and the seg fault should be happening on the return 0;

```
functioncall()
{

   Loads of SDL and other stuff

   SDL_Quit();
   gamestatemanager.~Gamestatemanager();
   return 0; // This is probably where i get the seg fault
}
```

Comment: Just let gamestatemanager go out of scope instead of call its destructor.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: You can create it by new and then destroy it by delete.

Comment: Remove the call to ~Gamestatemanager() and see if that helps, if not, we need more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the destructor for `gamestatemanager`, you're not supposed to call it explicitly.

It gets called when the object system cleans up your object.

If it's created as a local variable with something like:

```
Gamestatemanager gamestatemanager;
```

then it will be cleaned up when it goes out of scope. If it's allocated with `new`, you should `delete` it, at which point it will get cleaned up.

What you're probably finding here is that you're calling the destructor yourself, then it's being called *again* when the object goes out of scope. That's unlikely to end well :-)

Answer (score 0):

The destructor for an object is invoked automatically when that object goes out of scope. There is no need to call it explicitly.

```
int functioncall()
{
   Gamestatemanager gamestatemanager;
   ... 
   SDL_Quit();
   return 0;
} // The destructors for all local objects are called.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `gamestatemanager` is a local variable.

You are calling its destructor explicitly and then compiler calls destructor again implicitly (while "cleaning-up" the stack on return from function `functioncall()`), that causes segmentation fault.

Get rid of `gamestatemanager.~Gamestatemanager();` and it should be fine. Destructor will be called during stack unwiding implicitly.